# How to replace strings in the values of a particular custom field in all posts?

Tags: wordpress, replace, wordpress-theming, str-replace

I have a custom field of name: **embed**, thousands of wordpress posts are with this custom field with its value of an external player:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxx" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I need to modify these values from 560 **to 700** and 315 **to 450**.

I have a problem in the layout of a project, because of these standard dimensions, I've made a change that requires this change:

```
<iframe width="700" height="450" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxx" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How to make this str_replace in the **embed** custom field in all wordpress posts?

I can display these values directly in post_content with the values I need, so **another solution would be to avoid displaying this value of custom field embed in all posts** to avoid two players.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: 1. You have to add code in the question, 2. In your code referenced, there is no word `embed` at all.

Comment: embed, is the default custom field that is commonly used
  in wordpress to store embeds like youtube, vimeo etc ... is a custom field that everyone knows, I do not see in my theme any embed word (grep -R does not find), but when I'm in post edit, there's custom field with values I do not want, wordpress uses embed to publish external players, and this is in my post_edit, it is for those who understand the core of wordpress. https://imgur.com/a/4rSov  this is not an isolated case, it don't needs a code to analyze, it is for those who know how to exchange values of a custom fields.